# Join 2 tables that has different ID records in entity framework

Tags: c#, database, oracle, linq, entity-framework

So what happen is I have 2 tables like this:

```
ID     TIME     LOC              
01     10:00     A                          
02     8:00      B                  
03     8:00      C      
04     8:00      B
```

and

```
ID     TIME     LOC     NETVAL     INDIVALUE     
05     10:00     A       4          3           
06     8:00      B       7          5           
07     8:00      C       1          2
```

How do I join them so that I have something like:

```
ID     TIME     LOC    NETVAL     INDIVALUE  
01     10:00     A                          
02     8:00      B                  
03     8:00      C      
04     8:00      B     
05     10:00     A       4          3           
06     8:00      B       7          5           
07     8:00      C       1          2
```

I am using entity framework 5.0 to work with an ORACLE 11G... please help guys

Edit: Here what I have:

```
var last = qu.Concat<Object>(sm_list);
```

Give me error: `System.ArgumentException: DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes`

Note that qu and sm_list is not the same type nor implement same interface.

Comment: Questions that are merely requirements with no effort shown are not usually well received on Stack Overflow. Instead, show (in code) what has been attempted to far to solve the problem and what issues are currently being encountered along with a specific, answerable, objective question.

Comment: In Linq it would be `Concat` - in SQL it would be `UNION`.  Try one (or both) of those.

Comment: Not that I haven't tried. I couldn't use a Union cause these are not implement the same interface.

Comment: With concat, I get this error: AnonymousType#1 does not contain a definition for concat.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: DJ Kraze, I tried that one but I don't think it does the trick for me. I used the concat as above. sm_list and qu do not implement the same interface.

Comment: Seriously... I hope I get some answers or at least wait a little for clarification before downvoting me like that.

Comment: Unfortunately some people are very impatient with what they consider poor questions.  Perhaps they see their downvotes as an encouragement for you to improve your question.  Of course, they almost never come back to upvote your edited version.

Comment: People like that don't help new members like me grow, rather prevent us from participating. I do not consider myself a good coder by any mean, that why I ask a lot of questions. Sometimes, my search phrases don't return any good source, and believe me. I only ask when it is my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Note that qu and sm_list is not the same type nor implement same
>   interface."

And that's what the error message complains of:

```
DbUnionAllExpression requires arguments with compatible collection ResultTypes
```

You need to make the two result sets have the same projection before you can concatenate them.  You can do this by either adding dummy elements to the first collection (and populating them with null or empty strings or whatever) or else excluding the extra columns from the second collection.

Comment: I see, so that why. Thank you sir. This is what I expect from the beginning, not some arbitrary complain about my way of phrasing the question and then never come back.